# Do I use Rvest or read.txt() function and how with the following data

Tags: r, file, import, rvest

I wish to Import 100 text files from a website , but how do I wrangle them into the format I need.
Here is a sample of the data:

```
NOTE: futures symbols begin with the character @
      index symbols begin with the character $

Symbol (option symbols)           hv20  hv50 hv100    DATE   curiv Days/Percentile Close
****************************************************************
*  Data generated by McMillan Analysis Corp.    Copyright 2019 *
*   www.optionstrategist.com                800-724-1817       *
****************************************************************
$BKX                                22    18    22  190211   21.42    15/ 20%ile   91.76
$DJX                                10    11    20  190322   16.24   600/ 84%ile  255.02
$HGX                                16    15    23  190322   22.61   378/ 70%ile  286.36
$MNX
```

the files are from a subscription website and are saved as text eg.
vh_sym_20190322, If anyone could help me it would be appreciated.
I not only need to download bulk text files but then I need to wrangle them so that I only have the headers eg. "Symbol", "hv28" etc, and the data with Symbols and numbers eg. "$BKX", "22" etc, thanks again to anyone who can offer assistance.
PS. I subscribe to this companies data.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you would use either `Rvest` or `read.txt`. (Spelling is critical when telling computers what to do.) I would use `readLines` to get them into R and then `read.fwf` once you have removed all the crud.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a file *just like that*, this works:

```r
cn <- read.fwf("~/Downloads/foo.txt", c(34, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 16, 6), skip=3, comment.char="*", header=F, n=1)
cn
#                                   V1   V2     V3     V4       V5       V6               V7
# 1 Symbol (option symbols)            hv20   hv50  hv100     DATE    curiv  Days/Percentile
#       V8
# 1  Close
cn <- make.names(trimws(unlist(cn)))
cn
# [1] "Symbol..option.symbols." "hv20"                    "hv50"                   
# [4] "hv100"                   "DATE"                    "curiv"                  
# [7] "Days.Percentile"         "Close"                  
dat <- read.fwf("~/Downloads/foo.txt", c(34, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 16, 6), skip=4, comment.char="*", header=FALSE)
colnames(dat) <- cn
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  8 variables:
#  $ Symbol..option.symbols.: Factor w/ 3 levels "$BKX                              ",..: 1 2 3
#  $ hv20                   : int  22 10 16
#  $ hv50                   : int  18 11 15
#  $ hv100                  : int  22 20 23
#  $ DATE                   : int  190211 190322 190322
#  $ curiv                  : num  21.4 16.2 22.6
#  $ Days.Percentile        : Factor w/ 3 levels "    15/ 20%ile  ",..: 1 3 2
#  $ Close                  : num  91.8 255 286.4
```

You may want to update the column names and/or include `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. After that, you'll have a bit of data-cleaning, for example `Days.Percentile` appears to be a combined cell that was less-trivial to clean up with fixed-width reading alone.

Comment: It works great except there was 21 rows of junk it was truncated to 3 when pasting into stack overflow, hower the table is correct but I still have about 17 rows of JUnk,

Comment: cn <- read.fwf("~/2_R Library & Code/RWorkFiles/McMillan Volatility/vh_sym_20190322.txt", c(34, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 16, 6), skip=21, comment.char = "*", header=F, n=1)
cn
cn <- make.names(trimws(unlist(cn)))
cn
# [1] "Symbol..option.symbols." "hv20"                   
dat <- read.fwf("~/2_R Library & Code/RWorkFiles/McMillan Volatility/vh_sym_20190322.txt", c(34, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 16, 6), skip = 4, comment.char = "*", header = FALSE)
colnames(dat) <- cn
str(dat)

Comment: Here is the Junk

Comment: 1
hv50: 50-day historical volatil
ity
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
2
hv100: 100-day historical volati
lity
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
3
DATE: date of last OPTION data
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
4
(options don't trade eve
ry d
ay on
every
underlyi
ng
NA
NA
5
cur_iv:the implied volatility of
the
se opt
ions o
n DATE
NA
NA
NA
6
Days:the number of days back for
whi
ch imp
lied v
olatilit
y has

Comment: But the table starts a line below fine, what is the command to delete the junk just use remove rows from data table command?

Comment: Your first time you skipped 21 lines, but your second time (when we actually read the data) you skipped only 4 lines, it should be 22 (if 21 was correct before).

Comment: Thank you very much it has worked like a charm, I use several times a week, thank you so much.

Comment: njoj, is there a reason you *un-*-accepted the answer? Is there a nuance that this is not handling correctly?

Comment: no I did not mean to unanswer, I just clicked on it and it would not change back.

Comment: That's good to know. Only *you* have the authority to "accept" an answer. The only way you are denied the ability to do it (short of network glitches) is if the question has been closed for some reason. Please try again, thank you!

Comment: Has the answer accepted I clicked the icon, I am a bit thick and confused with using stackoverflow

Comment: I am not sure if you will get this comment, I wish to ask a pertinent question, I have many similar tasks on such like data, but I can not get the read.fwf, fixed widths right, I know it sounds incredibly stupid, it looked straight forward, I checked the length of the longest character in the column and added one character for  space and combined in a format such as you did for eg. like this  c(34, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 16, 6), skip=3, comment.char="*", header=F, n=1), but after 2 hours I gave up and went back excel .There is obviously something as plain as the nose on my face which I can not see?

Comment: I can't really comment on that without a bit more information. I suggest you research a bit on SO for similar questions and (assuming you've already done that) open a new question. Comments are really poorly structured to deal with new content like that.

Comment: Cheers, I will put some thought into how I approach the question, a lot of experienced programmers and data analysts get rather terse and piqued at the approach taken by someone new to a new platform like R even though they may be an expert in Excel and VBA and fortran. Their clumsiness and general illiteracy offends.

Comment: If i can parse the data in fixed format successfully in excel then the column widths have to be right so then it narrows down to syntax or coding semantic errors in R, that will be a helpful starting point for a question,to not look too stupid. thx

Comment: I have no "tricks" for FWF formats, to be honest. I test and fail and test something else until it works. Often I find myself just highlighting a range and counting characters (in emacs), recording the counts as I go. Nothing magical, sorry.